# Closing RT windows in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I used to be able to close RT apps (Reader, Mail, Settings etc) on my Windows 8.1 laptop by hovering to the top of the screen. A black bar slides in with on the right side a red cross. This closes the app as usual.

Now somehow (I am not aware of any updates) I can't close the apps this way anymore. I am using Alt + Tab to get out of the fullscreen apps which gets quite annoying.

With my fingers I can drag the app to the bottom of the screen and the app closes, returning to the Windows 8 Start screen. This on contrary to the red close button, which returned to the previously opened app (I much more like that behaviour). Also working with a mouse in a desktop setting, this doesn't work.

How am I able to return the red cross for RT apps?

/edit:

I now notice the whole active borders are gone. Sticking to the left, the previous apps don't appear. Sticking to the right, the blue bar with settings etc doesn't appear. Swiping my finger from the right border inwards does still work. It doesn't matter if I am using an external mouse or the trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the "charms" didn't work until I rebooted again. Now, it is all working again. I have no idea why, but apparently it still an issue to reboot to solve your Windows problems.